# ios: No results from Google Analytics

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, analytics

I am not receiving results from Google Analytics in my iOS app.

I am starting the tracker in my app delegate like so (I have obscured my ID with Xs):

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-1"
                                       dispatchPeriod:10
                                             delegate:nil];
```

I am attempting to track pageviews in the viewWillAppear method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"SearchViewController" withError:nil];
}
```

These trackPageview calls are returning YES, which would seem to indicate successful tracking, but the stats are not showing up in my Analytics console. I have waited 48 hours, and still nothing.

Is there anything else I should be doing? Anything wrong with my code?

I cannot use Easy Tracker because my project contains UITableViewControllers and because I am tracking events as well.

**EDIT:** Now I've implemented the delegate methods as well, and it tells me that the hits are being successfully dispatched.

I have double-checked that my ID is correct.

I am using version 1.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to figure out the above problem, but it turns out that using the new 2.0 beta works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be okay. I can't think of anything other than the fact that your account ID might have been pasted incorrectly.

Comment: The ID is correct. The delegate methods indicate that the hits are being dispatched successfully, but they aren't showing up in analytics.